# Why printf output of the variable is different

Tags: c, printf

I could not know why it happen! Want to know the reason.

```
{
int i=01;
printf("%d\n",i);
}
output: 1
```

but

```
{
int i=011;
printf("%d\n",i);
}
output: 9
```

Does anybody have the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

011 = Octal, (1*8)+1=9 ........................

Answer (score 11):

`011` is an octal constant. `11 (b8) = 9 (b10)`.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.4.4.1 Integer constants**
>   An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only.

Comment: why it will print octal number where as I have given a decimal integer value!

Comment: Because your numeric constant starts with a `0`. Read the quotation.

Comment: @Iqbal Yes, of course, `1*8 + 2*1 = 10`. If you start your literals with a 0, it's an octal literal. Try using the `%o` format in `printf`.

Comment: Read the quotation ;) prefix 0 for an octal constant (base 8) (and prefix 0x or 0X or simply x or X for hexadecimal base 16)

Answer (score -1):

```
The numbers which are preceded by 0 is called octal numbers in c programming .
to evaluate such an expression we simply follow a conversion rule of converting octal to decimal number system
For conversion the following steps are  to be proceed
such as 011
here 0 indicate the number is octal 
and we are require to convert 11 which is (base 8) to decimal (base 10)

11= 1x8^1+1x8^0
   =8+1
   =9
```