# printf with "%d" of numbers starting with 0 (ex "0102") giving unexpected answer (ex '"66")

Tags: c, hex, printf, octal

I used below code in my printf statement.

```
void main()
{
    int n=0102;
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

This prints 66 as the answer. I also changed the value of variable n to 012. It gives the answer 10. Please help me regarding how this conversion is done???

Comment: `0102` is being interpreted as octal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why printf output of the variable is different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321248/why-printf-output-of-the-variable-is-different)

Comment: What's amusing is that this was tagged [tag:octal] to begin with!

Comment: Come on people. (S)he already knows it is octal (see the octal tag). The question is about why it does not print as octal.

Comment: @EricSchaefer Come on man. If he read the manual for `printf()`, he would have found that one has to use `%o` for that. This is a classic RTFM question, for which it is not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Still do all the answer miss the point.

Comment: @EricSchaefer No, yours doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because when the first digit of a number (integer constant) is `0` (and second must not be `x` or `X`), the compiler interprets it as an octal number. Printing it with `%d` will give you a decimal value.
To print octal value you should use `%o` specifier

```
   printf("%o", n);
```

### 6.4.4.1 Integer constants:

> 1. An integer constant begins with a digit, but has no period or exponent part. It may have a prefix that specifies its base and a suffix that specifies its type.
> 2. A decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit and consists of a sequence of decimal
>      digits. **An octal constant consists of the prefix 0 optionally followed by a sequence of the
>      digits 0 through 7 only**. A hexadecimal constant consists of the prefix 0x or 0X followed
>      by a sequence of the decimal digits and the letters a (or A) through f (or F) with values
>      10 through 15 respectively.

---

### Integer Constants:

1.**Decimal constants**: Must *not* begins with `0`.

```
 12  125  3546
```

2.**Octal Constants**: Must begins with a `0`.

```
 012 0125 03546
```

3.**Hexadecimal Constants**: always begins with `0x` or `0X`.

```
 0xf 0xff 0X5fff
```

Comment: That's probably why (s)he used the 'octal' tag?

Answer (score 4):

You tell printf to print the value in decimal (%d). Use %o to print it in octal.

Answer (score 1):

any numeric literal starting with `0` followed only by numbers is taken as an octal number.
Hence

```
0102 = (1 * 8^2) + (0  * 8^1) + (2 * 8^0)  = 64 + 0 + 2 = 66
012 = (1 * 8^1) + (2 * 8^0) = 8 + 2 = 10
```

Comment: Not any, what about 0x10?

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is when you used 0 before 102 compiler is considering it as a octal number. this is a rule. and when you are using %d to print the number it is converting the octal number into decimal number. that why you are getting 66 which is decimal form of octal 102.