# When displaying the value of variable "int a = 011", I get 9. Why?

Tags: c, decimal, octal

With this code snippet:

```
int a = 011;
printf("a = %d", a);
```

Why is the result

> a = 9

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`011` is an octal value and its decimal equivalent is 9. Preceding integer literal with `0` indicates octal value.
Use `%o` specifier in `printf` to print the value in octal.

Comment: I got an integer overflow when I wanted to count the amount of dupes for this question. But on the C tag there are just almost no users, who care about that. (It's like yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19652607/3933332)

Comment: @Rizier123; I would say I am a lazy guy, yes a lazy guy.

Answer (score 10):

A leading `0`, in an `int` literal or `int` constant, represents the [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) value. It is called an octal constant.

Related: `C11` standard, chapter 6.4.4.1, *Integer constants*, Paragraph 3,

> An octal constant consists of the prefix `0` optionally followed by a sequence of the digits `0` through `7` only.

Answer (score 8):

With `0` at the beginning of of a numeric literal, you specify the octal system. And `11` in the octal system is `1*8 + 1 = 9`.